# Python Tornado max_buffer_size across all requests

Tags: python, tornado

I know I can set `max_buffer_size` in [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/iostream.html) to limit the amount of data that can be uploaded to the server. But what I am trying to do is restrict the total amount of data across *all* requests to my Tornado server.

For example, I have 500 simultaneous requests being sent to my Tornado server. Each request is uploading 1MB of data.  I want my Tornado server to reject connections when >150MB of data has been received across all requests. So the first 150 requests will be received, but then the next 350 will be rejected by Tornado before buffering any of that data into memory.

Is it possible to do this in Tornado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not currently a way to set a global limit like this (but it might be a nice thing to add).

The best thing you can do currently is to ensure that the memory used by each connection stays low: set a low default `max_body_size`, and for RequestHandlers that need to receive more data than that, use `@stream_request_body` and in `prepare()` call `self.request.connection.set_max_body_size(large_value)`. With the `@stream_request_body` decorator, each connection's memory usage will be limited by the `chunk_size` parameter instead of reading the whole body at once. Then in your `data_recieved` method you can `await` an allocation from a global semaphore to control memory usage beyond the chunk size per connection.