# Increase Tornado read buffer size when using it with Dask

Tags: python, tornado, dask-distributed

I'm trying to run a simulation of a FWI(Full waveform inversion) with Devito, following this [tutorial](https://slimgroup.github.io/Devito-Examples/tutorials/04_dask/) in a distributed system with Dask. Bellow a certain number of receivers(around 80) the program runs fine. Above this I get the following message:

```
 File "fwi_v3.py", line 170, in <module>
   d_obs = forward_modeling_multi_shots(geometry1, client, save=False)
 File "fwi_v3.py", line 91, in forward_modeling_multi_shots
   shots.append(futures[i].result()[0])
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 222, in result
   result = self.client.sync(self._result, callback_timeout=timeout, raiseit=False)
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 832, in sync
   return sync(
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 340, in sync
   raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 324, in f
   result[0] = yield future
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
   value = future.result()
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 247, in _result
   result = await self.client._gather([self])
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1880, in _gather
   response = await future
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1931, in _gather_remote
   response = await retry_operation(self.scheduler.gather, keys=keys)
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 385, in retry_operation
   return await retry(
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 370, in retry
   return await coro()
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 883, in send_recv_from_rpc
   result = await send_recv(comm=comm, op=key, **kwargs)
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 682, in send_recv
   raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 528, in handle_comm
   result = await result
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 2867, in gather
   data, missing_keys, missing_workers = await gather_from_workers(
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 78, in gather_from_workers
   r = await c
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 3255, in get_data_from_worker
   return await retry_operation(_get_data, operation="get_data_from_worker")
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 385, in retry_operation
   return await retry(
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py", line 370, in retry
   return await coro()
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 3235, in _get_data
   response = await send_recv(
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 666, in send_recv
   response = await comm.read(deserializers=deserializers)
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 195, in read
   n = await stream.read_into(frame)
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 490, in read_into
   self._try_inline_read()
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 857, in _try_inline_read
   pos = self._read_to_buffer_loop()
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 770, in _read_to_buffer_loop
   if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
 File "/home/murilo/.conda/envs/devito/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 911, in _read_to_buffer
   raise StreamBufferFullError("Reached maximum read buffer size")
tornado.iostream.StreamBufferFullError: Reached maximum read buffer size
```

I am a little unsure messing directly with Tornado since I've only touched Dask until this point. Setting the memory limit when initializing a `LocalCluster` would help? I've currently set it to 0, to have no memory restrictions.

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tornado max\_buffer\_size across all requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585501/python-tornado-max-buffer-size-across-all-requests)

Comment: It brings up more questions! Since tornado is working under the hood of Dask, I'm unsure how to define requests in tornado and apply those to Dask.